# Can't add new contact in People app on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: insider-preview, contacts, windows-10-mobile, people

I just upgraded my 640 XL from 8.1 to 10 and now I don't see any contacts in my People app. Clicking the + button to add new contacts causes the app to exit and I'm left back at the start screen.

Can anyone suggest a fix please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a hard reset worked.

I was resisting that but it turned out well, I just had to reset a few things, and obviously lost conversations etc. but the re-install of the OS and restore of the backup worked smoothly.

I can now happily add & edit contacts.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 Phone, it is very common to encounter an error like this.  As of now, you will need to use alternatives to this.

One way is if that person has text you or called you, click on that number and press the save icon.  Then click on add a contact.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your account and then sync your phone. Saved contacts in your people part of your account will be display.
but unfortunately I missed a lot of my contacts.
Microsoft must be warned people before updating to win10 but they did not and so many people lost their contacts list!